# I cannot install java from the software center

Tags: software-center, java, openjdk

I can't install openJDK from the software center, I get the error:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-lib_7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre_7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/icedtea-7-jre-jamvm_7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

It tells me to check my internet connection but I am connected (or how else could I post this).

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, better stick to OpenJDK6. Many apps depends on that 6 version. Its my personal opinion though :)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the content of the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You are trying to download version openjdk-7-jre_7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10_amd64.deb, but when you check here [LINK](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/), closest available version is openjdk-7-jre_7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10.1_amd64.deb, so it looks like you have to refresh apt package list. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK

Installation of Java Runtime Environment

1. Install the [openjdk-6-jre](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-6-jre) package using any installation method.
2. Install the [openjdk-7-jre](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-7-jre) package using any installation method.

Browser plugin

1. Install the [icedtea6-plugin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/icedtea6-plugin) package using any installation method.
2. Install the [icedtea-7-plugin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/icedtea-7-plugin) package using any installation method.

This plugin works with the main browsers: Firefox, Chromium, Google Chrome, and Epiphany.

On Konqueror, go to Settings → Configure Konqueror... and from menu select Java & JavaScript, then tick Enable Java globally option.

SDK (Software Development Kit)

In Java parlance the Java Development Kit (JDK) is sometimes used for SDK. (More about that here.)

```
Install the [openjdk-6-jdk][5] package using any installation method.

Install the [openjdk-7-jdk][6] package using any installation method.
```

Alternative Virtual Machines

Most users won't need to worry about these, but if you use an architecture (e.g. PowerPC) that defaults to the Zero Virtual Machine (VM), then you may see a significant performance increase if you switch to:

```
JamVM: This is the default VM for ARM in 11.10. Install the icedtea-6-jre-jamvm package if available. If it is not, then compile instructions can be found here.

Cacao: Ensure the icedtea-6-jre-cacao package is installed.

Zero/Shark: Shark is a just-in-time (JIT) compiler for Zero. Install the openjdk-6-jre-zero package if available. On architectures which use the Zero VM as the default, the openjdk-6-jre-zero package contains the Shark VM.
```

To use a different VM other than the default, just add the appropriate option to the command you normally use. For example:

```
java -jamvm|-cacao|-shark|-zero -version
```

See the file /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-powerpc/docs/README.Debian (or its equivalent) and the other documents in that directory for more information. Note, the IcedTea browser plugin will use the default VM (which you can change in the file /etc/java-6-openjdk/jvm.cfg).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

In `sources.list`, replace `archive` and `security` with `old-releases`.

For example:

Replace `archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

Reference: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=123935

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend downloading Java from Oracle by visiting https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java17

The direct link is this: https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb

It works like a charm and is very reliable and dependable.
Downloading from everywhere else was broken, but this still worked.